# MVVM Read data from view to model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I want to read user input data from view (e.g. filter criteria for querying data such as date, name, etc.) to viewmodel. To do that, I used two-way binding between viewmodel and view elements (i.e. textbox in this case). The view is automatically loaded when a viewmodel is assigned as follows:

```
<DataTemplate x:Shared="False" DataType="{x:Type vm:MyViewModel}">
    <view:MyView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

If the view is loaded the first time, every thing is fine. But if user reloads the view, then only the viewmodel is created and the view is reused (I already set x:Shared="False" as you can see). In that case, all user input (e.g. filter criteria) is lost on the newly created viewmodel. Could you please tell me what is the suitable approach to solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean with reloaded? Navigate back and forth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not recreate ViewModels but have static references to each after they have been created for the first time. You could utilize e.g. [MVVM Light](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLight/) to help accomplish this.

Example:

```
namespace SomeNamespace.ViewModel
{
    // This class contains static references to all the view models 
    // in the application and provides an entry point for the bindings.
    public class ViewModelLocator
    {
        static ViewModelLocator()
        {
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<LoginViewModel>();
        }

        // Reference to your viewmodel    
        public LoginViewModel LoginVM 
        { 
            get { return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<LoginViewModel>(); } 
        }

        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Where ViewModelLocator is defined in `App.xaml` as

```
<Application.Resources>
    <vm:ViewModelLocator xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:SomeNamespace.ViewModel" 
                         x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />
```

And in your Views bind DataContext to Locators properties.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="SomeNamespace.View.LoginPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=LoginVM}">
    ...

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Comment: +1 for MVVM Light suggestion. While it's cool to try to do things on your own why reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: Currently, I have a MainView containing a SubView which is loaded on-the-fly using: <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=CurrentViewModel}"/>. In the MainViewModel, the SubView is loaded using: this.CurrentViewModel = new SubViewModel(); With your suggested method, how could I load the corresponding SubView in the MainViewModel source code

Comment: With this info, not really sure without major changes... but maybe have 
`<ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=SubVM}"/>` and 
`public SubViewModel SubVM { get { return _subVM ?? (_subVM = new SubViewModel()); } }`

Comment: Thank you! According to your answer, we create instances of views and viewmodels one time and never release them. So, is it efficient to always keep those instances? If I have many views and viewmodels, each of them may have big data then will it has problem with memory?

Comment: Not views necessarily but datacontexts in case you need to preserve them. I have lots of VMs in e.g. WP apps and it has never been an issue.

Comment: If in doubt, you can always profile your application (memory usage among others) from Analyze menu in Visual Studio.